# .Net Localization with multiple languages

Tags: .net, web, localization

My understanding is that when you set CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture to for instance "da-DK" it will look for resource files in "da-DK", then "da", then fall back to the invariant culture. This works well for Desktop applications, because operating systems are not typically multi-lingual. For websites however this is not necessarily the case.

Let say I have a visitor whose browser insists the user wants "da_DK", "de_DE" and "en_GB", that is Danish if it exists, then German, then British English as a fallback.

Is there any way to accommodate this preference using the .Net 4 localization framework?

And no, this is not a thought experiment. :)

**EDIT**

Just to be clear, the problem is not getting the localization headers from the web request. The problem is setting the CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture in such a way that it will check resource files in order, rather than just checking for one.

Alternatively a way to check whether the CurrentUICulture has matching resx files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after :

[HttpRequest.UserLanguages()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userlanguages.aspx)

This returns the array of user languages in preference order.  Probably a good idea to allow them to change whatever localization you apply against this information, however, in case their browser configuration does not accurately reflect what they really want.

Update :

To check if the resources exist use :

[ResourceManager.GetResourceSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset.aspx)

Here you can set `tryParents` to false.  The method will return `null` if no resources exist.  You can then proceed to try the next preferred culture returned in the header.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified. The problem is not getting the header information. The problem is telling .Net to do a more exhaustive CultureInfo search than it does by default.